# I don't know why but one out of 5 sprites I created in Scratch is not working as desired

Tags: mit-scratch

I was trying to make a simple game using scratch but my lives counter is not working for one of the object. It is working for other 2 sprites. Everything is same. See if anyone can help.

Comment: Could you please attach screenshots / screen recordings?

Comment: I have uploaded the video here because I don't know how to upload on stack overflow. So, please follow this Youtube link: [6:16 PM] Ajay Gupta
https://youtu.be/blNMYKA0O-8
Scratch game problem. See if you can help. - YouTube

Comment: From the video: "I was thinking, I cannot use flag multiple times." That assumption is incorrect. Anyway, this problem demands thorough debugging. We cannot do that by watching a video.

Comment: @RuudHelderman would like to have a glance at it. I can add it to git you can check here:   https://github.com/joined-on-new-year/Problems-on-scratch/blob/07a3ede4ef2a237a15ea661f27c906954d4a0b39/Scratch%20Project%20(2).sb3 . Check here and hopefully you can help me.

Comment: Stack Overflow requires that a question be self-contained. I appreciate that's not as straightforward for Scratch as it is for other languages, but if your video or repo changes, the question, and any answers, becomes useless for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

From your project:

```
if (y position) = (-178) then
```

This is a bad idea. When a sprite 'glides', it will do so in small steps. Those steps are not guaranteed to be integer, and they are also not infinitesimal.
Meaning that the sprite may well skip y position -178, for example by stepping from -177.99 to -178.01.
Turn on the [stage monitor](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Stage_Monitor) of that sprite's y position block, and you'll get the idea; notice the fractional digits.

The solution: instead of checking if y position is *exactly* -178, check if it is *less than* -178.

```
if (y position) < (-178) then
```

So why didn't the other two sprites have the same problem? It was in the costume.
Scratch always makes sprites stop before the costume fully leaves the stage; always maintaining at least 30 pixels of overlap. Each sprite has a different costume, making them stop at a different y position. In the other two sprites, that y position just happened to match the number in the code. I recommend to make the suggested change in those sprites as well, to prevent the game breaking again in case you (or a remixer) ever changes costumes. Make sure to keep some slack space.